# Is it possible for an electron to absorb a photon of lower energy and emit a photon of higher energy?

Tags: photons

One electron can absorb more than one photon at a time but it is very less likely to happen. But why cannot it emit photons of more energy than it absorbed? The conservation of energy is still valid if we assume that the electron absorbed more no. of photons than it emitted.

Comment: What sort of "electron" are we talking about here? Free? Bound? What intensity of light are you shining on this poor electron that you think it could absorb multiple photons before emitting a single one? Where does the claim that the electron "cannot" emit high-energy photons under your assumption come from?

Comment: @ACuriousMind bounded electron. The intensity of Light is around $1$MW/m$^2$. And the claim that the electron cannot emit high energy photons after absorbing low energy photons come from a part of a textbook which is about photoelectric effect

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-harmonic_generation